# How to use Zoom Slider like the older version in Arcgis Javacript API 3.3?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm using Arcgis Javacript API 3.3. In this version zoom slider look like this.

[image]

And here, this is the older version.

[image]

Is there any way to make it like the older version?

Comment: Hi I am not sure but check out the esri.map reference (http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jsapi/#Map/isZoomSlider)

Comment: Check out this example (http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/mapconfig_customlabels.html) it contains zoom slider with labels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the following code with example and I have modified the sample and inserted few references.

Check out this JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u7WNt/6/  llet us know if you have any questions..thanks

Comment: Thanks.  `sliderStyle: "large"` is the key.